# shell script to get a output depent on the port number,getting the service name and stauts of the service?

Tags: linux, bash

for expample i tried this `sudo netstat -lntup | grep :80`  but it returns output of two written `80` and `8080` but i need signle output for the port number was given as a input parameter.

```
:~/Documents/scriptsampletest$ sudo netstat -lntup | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1135/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1192/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1135/nginx: master
```

Comment: `sudo ... | grep -Fw ':80'` ?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
port="80,9200,5601,9090"
email=test@gmail.com
if netstat -lntup | grep -Fw :$port
then
SERVICE = TO BE GET FROM FROM ABOVE IF COMMAND
  if  pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
    echo "$SERVICE is running"
    subject="$SERVICE at is running"
    echo "$SERVICE at is running" | mail -s "$subject" $email
else
    echo "$SERVICE stopped"
    subject="$SERVICE at is not running"
echo "$SERVICE at  is not running!!!" | mail -s "$subject" $email
    
fi

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is kind of a "Occam's razor" solution. Maybe adding a space will help?

I tried it worked for me.

`sudo netstat -lntup | grep ':80 '`

EDIT : To prevent mixup due to port number in other fields

`sudo netstat -lntup | tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f4 |grep ':80$'`

Comment: may be your port 8080 may be free

Comment: I don't think so, the pattern is colon (:) followed by port , followed by space.  For a complete solution.  ````sudo netstat -lntup | tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f4 |grep ':80$'```` can be tried.  It removes all but one space, delmits based on space, gets the 4th field and greps ':<port number>$' . This will prevent mixup due to port number in other fields.